# How to use recursion to get all children when each parent has an array of children?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a dictionary `d` of `parent:list(children)` as so:

```
d = \
{'accounts': ['nodate'],
 'retfile': ['bb', 'aa'],
 'snaps': [],
 'raw': ['pview', 'status'],
 'nodate': ['tainlog', 'retfile'],
 'mview': ['status', 'nodate'],
 'pview': [],
 'retlog': [],
 'aa': ['payfile'],
 'remfile': ['retlog'],
 'tainlog': ['remfile'],
 'payfile': [],
 'bb': ['payfile'],
 'balance': [],
 'status': ['accounts', 'snaps', 'nodate'],
 'charges': ['mview', 'raw', 'balance']}
```

For each key parent I want to get all decedents, so I was thinking of a recursion, so far I have this:

```
def get_all_descendants(t, l):
    l.extend(list(d[t]))
    if not d[t]:
        return set(l)
    for t1 in d[t]:
        return get_all_descendants(t1, l)
```

but this is not good as the `for` loop never really iterates over all the elements in the list rather the recursion starts over for the the first element.

For instance consider `'charges'`, my function is returning 11 elements:

```
{'accounts',
 'balance',
 'mview',
 'nodate',
 'raw',
 'remfile',
 'retfile',
 'retlog',
 'snaps',
 'status',
 'tainlog'}
```

While I want 15 elements (all the keys in `d` except 'charges') for instance missing `'pview'` (which is the child of `'raw'`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a depth first search. Just keep track of which items you've seen in a set. Then yield each one you haven't seen and yield from the result of recursive call:

```
def get_all_descendants(t, d, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set([t])
    for item in d[t]:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            yield item
            yield from get_all_descendants(item, d, seen)

list(get_all_descendants('charges', d))
```

This will give you this list:

```
['mview',
 'status',
 'accounts',
 'nodate',
 'tainlog',
 'remfile',
 'retlog',
 'retfile',
 'bb',
 'payfile',
 'aa',
 'snaps',
 'raw',
 'pview',
 'balance']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Mark's answer can be improved. Creating an inner `loop` means we will not check if `seen` is a set on *each* iteration. And moving the `if` outside of the `for` loop means you can skip many unnecessary checks on child nodes when the parent node has already been seen. The `loop` also uses the closure property so `d` and `seen` do not need to be passed to every recursive call -

```py
def dfs(t, d):
  seen = set()                    # unconditional
  def loop(t):                    # single parameter
    if t not in seen:             # if outside of loop
      seen.add(t)
      yield t
      for item in d[t]:
        yield from loop(item)
  return drop(loop(t), 1)         # exclude starting node from result
```

This depends on a generic `drop` helper which removes `n` items from an iterable -

```
def drop(it, n):
  for _ in range(n):
    next(it, None)
  return it
```

The output is identical -

```py
for node in dfs("charges", d):
  print(node)
```

```
mview
status
accounts
nodate
tainlog
remfile
retlog
retfile
bb
payfile
aa
snaps
raw
pview
balance
```

Comment: I take it that sets in Python are mutable, and thus left-to-right information flow happens by itself? (I'm thinking diamond shapes in descendants... ) or maybe not, since e.g. `payfile` appears  in your output twice...  (but not in Mark's?)

Comment: @WillNess I stayed up too late last night >_< and those duplicates went right past me. Thanks for catching that.